# How to create a BlueMix Devops Services Account

Tags: devops

I tried to create a devops Accout  per Instructions is a Lab I am doing:

> If you have not already created a Bluemix DevOps Services account, go
>   to https://hub.jazz.net to create one and link it to your Bluemix ID.

The page  "hub.jazz.net"  indicates I need to register to BlueMix first.
I click register Button and I am thrown into my BlueMix login. 
Never get chance to  create DEvops acct

Comment: Is this still an issue for you? If so, please add a pointer to the lab you are doing. A DevOps Services account is no longer needed for most of the Bluemix enablement, so you may be using a deprecated version.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Jazzhub has been retired? 
Try https://console.bluemix.net/devops/getting-started?

It is now called "Toolchains".